# Generate a fixed random number in a range based on a string in PHP

Tags: php

I need to generate a random number or hash that will be the same each time based on a string. This is done easily enough with the function crc32, however, I need it to be an integer between a range because the random number will be picking an item out of an array.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$min=0;
$max=count($myarray);
$number = crc32("Joe Jones");

$rnd = '.'.(string)$number;
//(Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))
$rand = round(($max-$min+1)*$rnd+$min);

echo $rand;
```

It seems to work, but it always picks lower numbers. It never picks the higher numbers.

Comment: Loop through a 100 times and post the comma separated results.

Comment: "random" and "same each time" sound kind of odd together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [mod](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (%). `$x % $n` will ensure an output between `0` and `$n-1` for any `$x`.

```
$myArray=range(1,1000);
$max=count($myArray); //1000
$number = crc32("Joe Jones"); //2559948711
$rand=$number % $max; //711
```

Also just a note about crc32: It *may* return a negative number if you run it on a 32 bit platform, so you may optionally want to do `abs(crc32($input))`

Comment: It returned a negative number for me on a 64 bit platform.

Comment: I knew there was a function that simplified this. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Your `crc32` function is producing a negative number. Change the line as follows:

```
$number = abs(crc32("Joe Jones"));
```

This turns that negative number in to a positive one. Also, you might want to consider multiplying that number if your your array count is is low. How high that goes is up to you.